# Python Side Effects I Don't Understand

Tags: python, side-effects

```
def group_move(group, damper):
    # Make a copy to test values
    new = group

    # See what the original group value is
    print("Test = " + str(group.ctris[0].p1.x))
    dr = some float
    dx = some float
    dy = some float
    # Make changes to new
    moveGroup(new, dr, dx, dy)
    # See if those changes produce allowed values
    if (off_board_check(new) == 1):
        damper += 2.0
        # Reset to original to try again
        print("Test Here = " + str(group.ctris[0].p1.x))
        group_move(group, damper)
    else:
        # If everything is on the board, then make the change
        group = new
```

If I run this, I will see that on the very first recursion, the `Test` print line produces a different value from the `Test Here` print line.  Why?  How is this code possibly affecting the values of `group`?  I am trying to pass an unchanged `group` onto the next recursive level of `group_move` in the case that the test values failed, but it seems that `group` is somehow being affected before I even make any recursive calls.  How is the above any different from this:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> y = x
>>> x = 7
>>> y = 77
>>> x
7
>>> y
77
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
# Make a copy to test values
new = group
```

The comment is incorrect. That does not make a copy. All that does is make a variable named `new` point at the same object that `group` is pointing at.

If you want to create an actual copy, you may want to look at [`copy.deepcopy()`](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy).

Comment: Why does it not make a copy?  See the simple example I added to my question.  In the Python interpreter, it appears that `y = x` has created a copy such that neither `y` nor `x` are affected by changes in the value of the other.

Comment: Yes, but that is because you're working with simple value types that can't be changed - `1`, `7`, etc (you can't redefine the value of `1`). Objects, on the other hand, are what are called "reference types" - variables that contain them do not actually contain the object, but instead a reference to one. Thus, assignment does not create a copy of the object, but only a copy of the reference... which still points to the same object.

Comment: The examples you added deal with *immutable* types (int), you can't change them, so assignment *looks* like a copy but isn't. You aren't changing the objects but what the names are bound to.

Comment: For a simple example, try this in the python interpreter: `a = []`, `b = a`, `a.append('foo')`, `b`.

Comment: Oh!  Wow.  Well, that's that.  I have to say I don't understand why Python did this.  It looks like I am interested in the copy module.

Comment: @Amber: There are no value types in Python. Everything is an object. It's a matter of ints being immutable and assignment rebinding references instead of mutating things.

Comment: Python did it because it's often quite handy to not create a new copy of an object every time it happens to be put into another variable. (In fact, it's fairly common in most programming languages - it's what pointers are all about in languages that support them.)

Comment: @CatPlusPlus - Sure, but that's really a semantics argument; an immutable reference type is effectively a value type.

Comment: @Amber: I see. I'm coming from Haskell.

Comment: @thoughtadvances Yes, functional languages tend to have a slightly different approach to everything, since almost none of their values are mutable.

Comment: @Amber: I changed that line to `new = copy.deepcopy(group)`, and I changed the last line to `return new`.  If there are no recursions, then it works as expected.  If it does any number of recursions, then it returns a NoneType!?  The recursion is always successfully converging.

Comment: @thoughtadvances Would need to see more of your code to diagnose that; you're calling functions which we can't see the code for.

Comment: "If it does any number of recursions, then it returns a NoneType!?" Because you don't propagate the result returned from the recursive call. Python is "imperative" enough that `return` works the way it does in imperative languages.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: OH!  That makes sense, but what is the Python solution to this problem?  I can not pass my result by reference, can I?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Ah!  I figured it out.  I do `return group_move(...)` in the if statement, which propagates the return.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
# Make a copy to test values
new = group
```

You are copying the **reference** of an **object**

Moreover your test isn't a "smart" one because, in your example, you're using **primitive type variables** and not **object**.

As a general rule remember that

> Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create bindings between a target and an object. **For collections that are mutable or contain mutable items**, a copy is sometimes needed so one can change one copy without changing the other. This module provides generic shallow and deep copy operations (explained below).

From [here](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
new = group
```

This means "`new` shall be a name for the result of evaluating the expression `group` (i.e., the thing currently named by `group`, since the expression is just a name)". That is an alias, not a copy.

```
x = 1
y = x
x = 7
y = 77
```

Same thing here. `x = 1; y = x` causes both of them to refer to an object that represents the integer `1`. `x = 7` causes `x` to stop referring to the `1` object and start referring to another object representing the integer `7`. Likewise for `y = 77`. The independence is not because of any copying (because there wasn't any) but because there is nothing in the code that specifies a change to the *referred-to object* (which in fact is impossible for `int`s in Python). When people expect this code to end up with x equal to 77 at the end, they are actually interpreting things inconsistently, expecting value semantics on some lines and reference semantics on others. **Both value semantics and reference semantics predict the actual result**.